# Strange binary classification result with a model that indicate it has been well-trained

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, keras, image-classification, convolutional-neural-network

**The problem :**
I am trying to build a model for binary classification for melanoma 'MEL' and nevus 'NV' the dataset is from ISIC archive [ISIC 2019](https://challenge2019.isic-archive.com/) but for 8 different type of skin lesion, I am using just two type as I mentioned (binary classification).

the two classes are unbalanced 10000 for 'NV' and 3000 for 'MEL'.

the dataset is splitted to train and validation.
I perform to solution for the problem : downsampling and Image augmentation.
the train folder is now contain two subfolder 'MEL' and 'NV' with 10000 image
te validation folder contain 904 image for each class.

[image]

using keras, I fine-tuned Densenet201, and used preprocessing function for densenet

```
from keras.applications.densenet import DenseNet201, preprocess_input
densenet_model = DenseNet201(input_shape=(224, 224, 3), include_top=False, weights="imagenet")
```

then i add some layers at the end of the pretrained model

```
#get the last layer shape
last_layer = densenet_model.get_layer('relu')
print('last layer output shape:', last_layer.output_shape)
last_output = last_layer.output

# Flatten the output layer to 1 dimension
x = layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(last_output)
# Add a fully connected layer with 512 hidden units and ReLU activation
x = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(x)
# Add a dropout rate of 0.5
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
# Add a final sigmoid layer for classification
x = layers.Dense(2, activation='sigmoid')(x)
# Configure and compile the model
model = Model(densenet_model.input, x)
```

I didn't freeze any layer, then I compile the model

```
optimizer = Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=None, 

decay=0.0, amsgrad=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=['accuracy','binary_accuracy'])

filepath = "densenet.h5"

# Declare a checkpoint to save the best version of the model
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(filepath, monitor='val_acc', verbose=1,
                             save_best_only=True, mode='max')

# Reduce the learning rate as the learning stagnates
reduce_lr = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_acc', factor=0.5, patience=2,
                              verbose=1, mode='max', min_lr=0.00001)

callbacks_list = [checkpoint, reduce_lr]

# Fit the model
history = model.fit_generator(train_batches,
                              steps_per_epoch=train_steps,
                              validation_data=val_batches,
                              validation_steps=val_steps,
                              epochs=20,
                              verbose=1,
                              callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

### The result :

```
    Epoch 1/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 793s 466ms/step - loss: 0.4436 - acc: 0.7890 - binary_accuracy: 0.7890 - val_loss: 0.3416 - val_acc: 0.8404 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8404

Epoch 00001: val_acc improved from -inf to 0.84043, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 2/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 720s 423ms/step - loss: 0.3447 - acc: 0.8450 - binary_accuracy: 0.8450 - val_loss: 0.3564 - val_acc: 0.8446 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8446

Epoch 00002: val_acc improved from 0.84043 to 0.84458, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 3/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 728s 428ms/step - loss: 0.2718 - acc: 0.8835 - binary_accuracy: 0.8835 - val_loss: 0.3785 - val_acc: 0.8487 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8487

Epoch 00003: val_acc improved from 0.84458 to 0.84873, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 4/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 726s 427ms/step - loss: 0.2051 - acc: 0.9172 - binary_accuracy: 0.9172 - val_loss: 0.3779 - val_acc: 0.8581 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8581

Epoch 00004: val_acc improved from 0.84873 to 0.85813, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 5/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 728s 428ms/step - loss: 0.1529 - acc: 0.9403 - binary_accuracy: 0.9403 - val_loss: 0.3923 - val_acc: 0.8581 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8581

Epoch 00005: val_acc did not improve from 0.85813
Epoch 6/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 728s 428ms/step - loss: 0.1163 - acc: 0.9553 - binary_accuracy: 0.9553 - val_loss: 0.4813 - val_acc: 0.8498 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8498

Epoch 00006: val_acc did not improve from 0.85813

Epoch 00006: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 4.999999873689376e-05.
Epoch 7/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 727s 427ms/step - loss: 0.0407 - acc: 0.9864 - binary_accuracy: 0.9864 - val_loss: 0.5726 - val_acc: 0.8667 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8667

Epoch 00007: val_acc improved from 0.85813 to 0.86670, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 8/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 728s 428ms/step - loss: 0.0287 - acc: 0.9904 - binary_accuracy: 0.9904 - val_loss: 0.5919 - val_acc: 0.8711 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8711

Epoch 00008: val_acc improved from 0.86670 to 0.87113, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 9/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 728s 428ms/step - loss: 0.0253 - acc: 0.9909 - binary_accuracy: 0.9909 - val_loss: 0.5453 - val_acc: 0.8720 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8720

Epoch 00009: val_acc improved from 0.87113 to 0.87196, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 10/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 730s 429ms/step - loss: 0.0216 - acc: 0.9927 - binary_accuracy: 0.9927 - val_loss: 0.5498 - val_acc: 0.8706 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8706

Epoch 00010: val_acc did not improve from 0.87196
Epoch 11/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 729s 428ms/step - loss: 0.0145 - acc: 0.9954 - binary_accuracy: 0.9954 - val_loss: 0.6332 - val_acc: 0.8822 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8822

Epoch 00011: val_acc improved from 0.87196 to 0.88219, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 12/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 731s 430ms/step - loss: 0.0176 - acc: 0.9939 - binary_accuracy: 0.9939 - val_loss: 0.6256 - val_acc: 0.8756 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8756

Epoch 00012: val_acc did not improve from 0.88219
Epoch 13/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 734s 432ms/step - loss: 0.0117 - acc: 0.9965 - binary_accuracy: 0.9965 - val_loss: 0.5959 - val_acc: 0.8838 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8838

Epoch 00013: val_acc improved from 0.88219 to 0.88385, saving model to densenet.h5
Epoch 14/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 736s 433ms/step - loss: 0.0132 - acc: 0.9958 - binary_accuracy: 0.9958 - val_loss: 0.7139 - val_acc: 0.8598 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8598

Epoch 00014: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385
Epoch 15/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 735s 432ms/step - loss: 0.0109 - acc: 0.9963 - binary_accuracy: 0.9963 - val_loss: 0.6139 - val_acc: 0.8720 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8720

Epoch 00015: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385

Epoch 00015: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 2.499999936844688e-05.
Epoch 16/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 734s 431ms/step - loss: 0.0048 - acc: 0.9980 - binary_accuracy: 0.9980 - val_loss: 0.6759 - val_acc: 0.8764 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8764

Epoch 00016: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385
Epoch 17/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 733s 431ms/step - loss: 0.0028 - acc: 0.9992 - binary_accuracy: 0.9992 - val_loss: 0.7179 - val_acc: 0.8805 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8805

Epoch 00017: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385

Epoch 00017: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 1.249999968422344e-05.
Epoch 18/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 734s 432ms/step - loss: 0.0014 - acc: 0.9996 - binary_accuracy: 0.9996 - val_loss: 0.7525 - val_acc: 0.8816 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8816

Epoch 00018: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385
Epoch 19/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 734s 431ms/step - loss: 0.0011 - acc: 0.9997 - binary_accuracy: 0.9997 - val_loss: 0.7580 - val_acc: 0.8803 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8803

Epoch 00019: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385

Epoch 00019: ReduceLROnPlateau reducing learning rate to 1e-05.
Epoch 20/20
1701/1701 [==============================] - 733s 431ms/step - loss: 8.0918e-04 - acc: 0.9997 - binary_accuracy: 0.9997 - val_loss: 0.7667 - val_acc: 0.8800 - val_binary_accuracy: 0.8800

Epoch 00020: val_acc did not improve from 0.88385
```

**the Confusion matrix :**

[image]

**the Classification Report from sklearn.metrics**

```
                    precision    recall  f1-score   support

 MEL                 0.48      0.47      0.48       904
 NV                  0.48      0.49      0.49       904

accuracy                                 0.48      1808
macro avg            0.48      0.48      0.48      1808
weighted avg         0.48      0.48      0.48      1808
```

## The dilemma

**as you can see, this is an utter trash model.
what you think the problem is ? please any suggestions, this is happening for a month without any improvement.
if you want to take a look to other piece of code I will post them .**

**this is the code for augmentation**

```
    class_list = ['MEL','NV']

    for item in class_list:

    # Create a temporary directory for the augmented images
    aug_dir = 'aug_dir'
    os.mkdir(aug_dir)

    # Create a directory within the base dir to store images of the same class
    img_dir = os.path.join(aug_dir, 'img_dir')
    os.mkdir(img_dir)

    # Choose a class
    img_class = item

    # List all the images in the directory
    img_list = os.listdir('base_dir/train_dir/' + img_class)

    # Copy images from the class train dir to the img_dir
    for fname in img_list:
        # source path to image
        src = os.path.join('base_dir/train_dir/' + img_class, fname)
        # destination path to image
        dst = os.path.join(img_dir, fname)
        # copy the image from the source to the destination
        shutil.copyfile(src, dst)

    # point to a dir containing the images and not to the images themselves
    path = aug_dir
    save_path = 'base_dir/train_dir/' + img_class

    # Create a data generator to augment the images in real time
    datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
        rotation_range=60,
        width_shift_range=0.1,
        height_shift_range=0.1,
        #zoom_range=0.1,
        shear_range= 0.2,
        horizontal_flip=True,
        vertical_flip=True,
        brightness_range=(0.9,1.1),
        fill_mode='nearest')

    batch_size = 50

    aug_datagen = datagen.flow_from_directory(path,
                                              save_to_dir=save_path,
                                              save_format='jpg',
                                              target_size=(224, 224),
                                              batch_size=batch_size)

    # Generate the augmented images and add them to the training folders
    num_aug_images_wanted = 10000  # total number of images we want to have in each class
    num_files = len(os.listdir(img_dir))
    num_batches = int(np.ceil((num_aug_images_wanted - num_files) / batch_size))

    # run the generator and create about 6000 augmented images
    for i in range(0, num_batches):
        imgs, labels = next(aug_datagen)

    # delete temporary directory with the raw image files
    shutil.rmtree('aug_dir')
```

**the preprocessing code**

```
    # Declare a few useful values
num_train_samples = train_len
num_val_samples = val_len
train_batch_size = 16
val_batch_size = 100
image_height = 224
image_width = 224
# Declare how many steps are needed in an iteration
train_steps = np.ceil(num_train_samples / train_batch_size)
val_steps = np.ceil(num_val_samples / val_batch_size)
    # Set up generators

datagenr = ImageDataGenerator(
    preprocessing_function= \
    keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input)


train_batches = datagenr.flow_from_directory(
    train_path,
    target_size=(image_height, image_width),
    batch_size=train_batch_size)

val_batches = datagenr.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=(image_height, image_width),
    batch_size=val_batch_size)

# Note: shuffle=False causes the test dataset to not be shuffled
test_batches = datagenr.flow_from_directory(
    val_path,
    target_size=(image_height, image_width),
    batch_size=val_batch_size,
    shuffle=False)
```

I am a new to the field so please, if you think this question is inappropriate,  don't just dislike the question and go,leave a comment that may help me and others to improve ourselves, to not ask question similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many points that you should check/try :
- use Flatten layer instead of GlobalMaxPooling2D (with optional conv2d layers to reduce spatial dimensions even more before the Flatten)
-  your final Dense layer should have only one unit and not two since you are doing binary classification
- no down sampling but balance classes in each batch with a training generator that you pass to fit_generator
- check that all your augmentations are not degrading any discrimitive information in the image
- larger learning rate like 1e-3
- increase the patience of ReduceLRonPlateau
- use Area Under the ROC Curve (aka AUC) as an evaluation metric. This is a much better metric in case of inbalanced dataset.

Comment: thank you Ismael for your efforts, I will test your suggestions and will reply to you.

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine I edited my answer with a new advice : 1 unit in the final Dense layer activated with sigmoid is enough for binary classification. It will output the probability of your input belonging to the positive class. And thus your ground truth is either 0 for negative class or 1 for positive class.

Comment: it  return an error 

ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (2,)

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine adapt your data generation so that your target (ground truth) is a scalar with value 0 or 1.

Comment: @GuissousAllaeddine you should also try to replace your GlobalMaxPooling2D layer by a simple Flatten layer. It will keep all information available to the subsequent Dense layer. You can add convolution layers before the Flatten layer if you want to reduce the dimension further.